# Check if Spreadsheet.getRange() Returns full cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a app script that deals with returning data from a spread sheet. However I am facing a weird error that at time at the beginning of the day the dataRows return via the code below returns empty, even though the actual spreadsheet had rows full of data, and this only happens the first time I try at the beginning of the day, the second time onwards it works fine.

```
var dataRows = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

So for example, if I try in the morning to submit my Google Form, dataRows gives me empty cells, however second time onwards I tried dataRows give me cells with correct data in it, not empty cells.

Notice the first param of getRange() is 2 because index 1 is the heading row, as seen in below image.

[image]

Also it appears that even though dataRows.length would have some valid length that actual data in it appears to be empty, for example dataRows[row][0].valueOf() is just empty.

Is there some way to check if the rows that I am getting from dataRows are valid rows not empty cells and If anyone can give suggestions as to why this would be heppening in the first place as I mentioned above, there is data in the spread sheet at specified row and column but getRange() returns me empty cells.

Please help.

Comment: The third parameter of `getRange` is the number of rows in the range, not the number of the last row in range. If you pass in `sheet.getLastRow()`, and your range begins with row 2, that guarantees you will get empty row at the end.

Comment: This question looks to have the XY Problem (reference http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/289691) as the question asks about how to check the result instead of how to get the expected result, I think. Please clarify what the question is really about.

Answer (score 1):

## Partial answer

Instead of

```
var dataRows = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

try

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
```

## Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange

Comment: This is helpful but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.